# Using LINQ .Select and .Any in single line

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I am looking to optimize some code to less lines and without the need for "for loops" using LINQ if possible. I saw a similar post asking for Select and Where in a single line but it wasn't exactly the same.
Suppose I have:

A list of elements in "**fields**" which has properties "**Id**" and "**Name**" which can be retrieved calling respectively **.Id** and **.Name**

```
Ex.  
fields[0] = Element  
fields[0].Id = 12345
fields[0].Name = Name01
```

I want to create a new list "**filteredIds**" containing the Id properties of selected fields.

```
This is the for loop version:  
List<Id> filteredIds = new List<Id>();
fields = {Element1, Element2, ...}; //List of Elements
List<string> selectedNames = new List<string>() {"Name01", "Name05", "Name10"};
foreach (Element e in fields):
          if (selectedNames.Contains(e.Name())
          {
          filteredIds.Add(e.Id);
          }
```

Can this be done in a single line like this in LINQ?

```
filteredIds = fields.Select(i => i.Id).Any(o => selectedNames.Contains(o.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: I was wondering if you ever thought how `Select()` or `Where()` are implemented?

Comment: You are almost there, `filteredIds = fields.Where(o => selectedNames.Contains(o.Name)).Select(i => i.Id).ToList();`

Comment: LINQ is not Siri. Sorry to be a bad stackoverflow guy but this question just shows zero research.

Comment: You can use `HashSet` instead of `List` for selected names to make it tiny tiny more performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any()` returns `true`/`false` values. You need to call `Where()` to actually filter results.

```
filteredIds = fields.Where(o => selectedNames.Contains(o.Name)).Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: If you put the `where` after the select you will not have an `o.Name` property. right?

Comment: @SimonWilson write up an answer :) I mean you did provide a solution in the comments above...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ...yeah, I know. I thought it was an "easy" one so gave the answer in a comment. Maybe next time. As long as the OP get's his answer I guess

Comment: Thank you Tanveer!

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct. You should use Where to filter the list, not Any.

Any returns a boolean which is true if at least one element in the list satisfies the predicate, while Where returns all the elements that satisfy the predicate.

You also need to apply the Where filter before the Select, as the name property is removed by the select.

Comment: Thank you Jonas!